# Search Lists in dict for Value, if found return dict identifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, search

Hard to explain so I will put an example below:

```
res = {
  "merchantPermissionsMap" : {
    "33427" : ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"],
    "12345": ["AAA", "CCC"],
    "67890": ["BBB"]
  }
}
```

So I need to search `res['merchantPermissionsMap']` for any occurrence of a permission, and if found return the corresponding id.

I know the below is wrong, but this is how I expect it to flow:

```
message = ''
for i in res['merchantPermissionsMap']:
    if 'BBB' in i:
        message += f" {i}"
print(f"BBB appears in{message}")
```

Output would be: `BBB appears in 33427, 67890`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking the `BBB` in key you should check value
here `i` is a key

```
for i in res['merchantPermissionsMap']:
    print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
33427
12345
67890
```

You should change your `if` condition `if 'BBB' in res['merchantPermissionsMap'][i]`

```
for i in res['merchantPermissionsMap']:
    if 'BBB' in res['merchantPermissionsMap'][i]:
        message += f" {i}"
print(f"BBB appears in{message}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to get the desired result

```
res = {
  "merchantPermissionsMap" : {
    "33427" : ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"],
    "12345": ["AAA", "CCC"],
    "67890": ["BBB"]
  }
}

appears = ", ".join([k for k,v in res["merchantPermissionsMap"].items() if "BBB" in v])

print(f"BBB appears in {appears}")
```

Output:

```
BBB appears in 33427, 67890
```

OR

your code, you are looping through the keys of the `merchantPermissionsMap` dict. Or loop through key and value via `.items()`

```
for k,v in res['merchantPermissionsMap'].items():
    if 'BBB' in v:
        message += f" {k}"
print(f"BBB appears in{message}")
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate through your dictionary to get desired output. Try below code ;

```
def search(res,string):
a=[]
for key, value in res.items():
    for k,v in value.items():
        if 'BBB' in v:
            a.append(k)
return a

print(search(res.'BBB'))
```